# Nombres avec suffixe autrement que 1er, 2e, 2de,

Tags: nombres, suffixes

Are there any other combinations of a number and a suffix in French? The examples I found were only ordinal numbers.

Comment: 3ème, 4ème etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a completely different context, you may encounter some suffixes in **street numbers**, such as :

> 5bis, 5ter, 5quater...

Typically, these cases happen for formerly bigger properties that were divided later:

| --- 3 --- | --- --- 5 --- --- | --- 7 --- |

becomes

| --- 3 --- | -- 5 -- |  -5bis- | --- 7 --- |

If you want to know more about it, you can [follow this link](https://www.culture-generale.fr/histoire/87-origine-des-bis-ter-quater-dans-les-numeros-de-rue) (fr).

Answer (score 2):

There is the same principle for quantities, with "aine" for sufix :

douz**aine** (dozen) : 12aine
, quinz**aine** (fifteen or so) 15aine 
, and all tens : 10aine, 20aine, 30aine...

100aine is the only hundred to be written this way

Edit : soixante-dizaine (70aine), quatre-vingtaine (80aine) and quatre-vingt-dizaine (90aine) are very rarely used.

Comment: I've never seen these abbreviations before. Not saying they don't exist, but they're certainly not common.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi L'abréviation -aine se rencontre sur le web mais est non standard. L'usage officiel mais rare est d'utiliser -ne, par exemple *une quinzaine d'hommes* = *une [15ne](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/15ne) d'hommes*